# I cant get to execute the two statements in my trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want both statements to be executed in my trigger. I can't get the following to work:

```
IF (flag = 'D') THEN
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO logs (id, author_id, action_done, description, old_value, new_value, create_date) 
     VALUES (null, (SELECT id FROM gallery WHERE flag = 'D'), 'Delete', 'Gallery', (SELECT filename FROM gallery WHERE flag = 'D'), '', NOW());
     DELETE FROM gallery WHERE flag = 'D';
END
END IF
```

Comment: Do INSERT SELECT instead of INSERT VALUES.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I tried your method and it's not working

Comment: Can you paste the error if you are getting any?

Comment: @SanenLongJa . . . You should show the entire trigger logic.

Answer (score 0):

I assume id field in logs table is a primary key and auto generated by system.

Try this:

```
IF (flag = 'D') THEN
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO logs (author_id, action_done, description, old_value, new_value, create_date) 
     select id, 'Delete', 'Gallery', filename, '', NOW() from gallery where flag='D'; 
     DELETE FROM gallery WHERE flag = 'D';
END
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id should auto increment and thus should not be one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your trigger is on the table `gallery`.  If so, your trigger should be a "before" or "after" trigger and you can do:

```
IF (flag = 'D') THEN
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO logs (author_id, action_done, description, old_value, new_value, create_date) 
         VALUES (old.id, 'Delete', 'Gallery', old.filename, '', NOW());    
END;
END IF
```

There is no need to repeat the `DELETE`.